# finding the coordinates of a point of intersection: 3d sphere and plane

Tags: algebra-precalculus, analytic-geometry, spheres

How to find the coordinates of one point on the interaction of the sphere $$(x-1)^2+(y-2)^2+(z-4)^2= 25$$ and the plane $z=4$.

I was trying to solve this I got it down to $x+y=8$ but then when I tried to solve it did not work. Please help me.

Answer (score 3):

Okay, so you first plug in z=4 (goes to 0):

$(x-1)^2+(y-2)^2+=25$

You should recognize this as a circle centered at $(1,2)$ with radius $5$.  Based on this, you can find different points.  For example, you can have $(1,7,4)$ as a solution.  If you got down to $x+y=8$, you went a little farther than necessary.  The trick is to notice the circle.  However, if you notice, I have 1+7=8

Comment: ok that kinda makes sense to me. where did you get the (1,7,4)?

Comment: I just got it thanks for your help